# how to pass parameters("Id's and classes") to the function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to pass 2 id's in a function using parameters in jquery.I don't know what's wrong with my code. Please help me solving this issue. My code is not working.How to use jquery functions? In the following code, I am trying avid writing multiple functions for each field.I want to write only one function and call it by parameters.How to do this? Please let me know. The function is not going inside the .click. Its showing error in console as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"("showing '#demo' value as null");. here is my code. Why is it showing demo as null I am not getting.Also, can we combine jquery and javascript and write code?. whether my way of writing code is correct or not? The code is not working. Also, please provide link to function parameters in jQuery. The readonly class is nither getting added to the input field class nor it is enabling after a click. I am not understanding whats wrong with my code.

My Jquery Code

```
    function myFunc(a, b)
        {
          console.log("enable and disable");
          $('a').click(function(){
           console.log("change to enable");
          if($(this).parents('.info-details').find('b').hasClass('readonly')){
           $(this).parents('.info-details').find('b').removeClass('readonly');
           $("b").prop("disabled", true);
          }
          else {
            $(this).parents('.info-details').find('b').addClass('readonly');
            $("b").prop("disabled", false);
          }
        });
      }
      document.getElementById("#demo").innerHTML = myFunc('#edit_data_email, #change_email');
    document.getElementById("#demo").innerHTML = myFunc('#edit_data_phone, #change_phone');
```

In the following code, they are doing exactly same. This code is for demo purpose.

Code Demo

```
        <body>
        <p>Setting a default value to a function parameter.</p>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="demo1"></p>
        <script>
        function myFunction(x, y) {
            if (y === undefined) {
                y = 0;}    
        return x * y;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 12);
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 12);
        </script>
        </body>
```

I want my code to work this way by passing parameters. In this example they are passing arguments to the parametere. I am trying the same thing But still it's not working.

Comment: `.find('b')` => `.find(b)`, `'b'` is a string, `b` is a variable

Comment: any solutions? How to do it? I am stuck on this from 2 days.

Comment: read the comment again

Comment: i am not getting it.

Comment: you have `'` in your find functions, but `a` and `b` are variables, remove the `'`

Comment: I am new to jqery. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: i removed ' its still not working

Comment: Thats not the only mistake here, i added an answer..

Answer (score 1):

Your code has more than one mistake..

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hquqcjjk/1/) with fully working code for reference.

1. Like @ztadic91 pointed out in a comment, you must use variables without quotes:

Working example:

```
var a = 1;
alert(a);
```

**Not** working example:

```
var a = 1;
alert("a");
```

---

2. You pass only one argument. You must quote both arguments seperatly:

What you made is this:

```
myFunc('a, b');
```

But you need to quote both of them seperatly:

```
myFunc('a', 'b');
```

---

3. You fill in the function result in you html, which is undefined. Simply call the function without the `.innerHTML = ...` stuff.

---

4. If you use `document.getElementById('...')` you do not need the `#` do indicate that it is a class.

---

Another thing is that not all of your code is jQuery it works also if it isn't jQuery but it is way shorter with the jQuery Syntax, replace this:

```
document.getElementById("#demo").innerHTML = ...;
```

with this

```
$("#demo").html(...);
```

---

After fixing all these faults, I recommend that you learn jQuery on a learning platform before making such deep stuff and asking questions that are hard to read and not easily reproducible...

---

Happy Coding,
Kalasch

Comment: hi, Kalasch Thank you for helping. When I click on edit, the field is getting enabled but when I again click on edit, the field is not disabling. Can you help me with this? It is not taking readolny class.

Comment: In my fiddle if have created and linked, it is working as requested. Please look at the fiddle for further help.

Comment: sir replaced fiddle code with my existing code. Still, it's not working. When I click on edit 2nd time, it's not disabling. Please help me with this.